# Windows: send Mouse/Keyboard event to background window?

Tags: windows, events, keyboard, mouse, dwm

My application is a fullscreen window which is rendering a designated other window (from dwm), for example Google Chrome. I would like to know if it's possible to send events (such as mouse keyboard events) to the specified window.

Of course the designated window has to stay in background, and my current application on the foreground.

My application is written in C++. I'm working on Windows 7/8.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what the name of the function is, but in the windows API there is a function to send a windows message to a specified window. I think this might work but im not sure if it is correct, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k30c7s8w.aspx

Comment: This solutions looks cool except than i'm using QT-creator + minGW. Do you have any soltions to include <afxwin.h> in a qt project ?

Comment: I have no idea what Qt is, I've read about it 100x. But, if you are using this in windows, every window in windows has a handle. You should be able to send any window any message if you have its handle  (I think).

Comment: I asked the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246770/does-any-program-language-library-that-interacts-with-windows-do-it-via-the-win3/25247034#25247034, and it looks like you should be able to use the WinAPI to get this done.

Comment: I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx

Example: 
    if (appli->ImScrolling())
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_VSCROLL, 0, 0);

This is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put it into an answer.

Based on this question [Does any program/language/library that interacts with windows do it via the WIN32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246770/does-any-program-language-library-that-interacts-with-windows-do-it-via-the-win3/25247034#25247034) you should be able to use the windows API to send a windows message to any window. All you need to get is that windows handle, or you could do a broadcast to all windows.

The specific function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx

Though that function will block until the windows responds and processes the message, this could hurt GUI performance. If you notice issues try implementing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644951(v=vs.85).aspx instead.

Comment: Actually i don't have any gui performances issues with SendMessage(), but i will check the callback function. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @AnotherUser you can't send keyboard events like WM_KEY* by SendMessage(), it doesn't change another app's keyboard state. you need to use SendInput(), but that doesn't have a target window, it sends to the focused one, but it's possible to set the focus even for a hidden window. People report that they could accomplish the same with PostMessage() and WM_KEY* though, but I couldn't do that, only SendInput()