# SendInput Mouse Click At X/Y

Tags: c#, input, click, mouse

I am trying to build a clickbot in C#, but i have some problems.

The click works, but it keeps clicking at the location where the cursor currently is located and not at the x and y position.

I used the following code and inserted the x and y positions.

```
        mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dx = 1809;
        mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dy = 93;
```

I also tried adding

```
            mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
```

[How to programmatically mouse move,click,right click and keypress, etc. in winform and wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094398/how-to-programmatically-mouse-move-click-right-click-and-keypress-etc-in-winfo)

```
public class MouseSimulator
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, ref INPUT pInputs, int cbSize);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct INPUT
    {
        public SendInputEventType type;
        public MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion mkhi;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public MouseInputData mi;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public KEYBDINPUT ki;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        public ushort wVk;
        public ushort wScan;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public int uMsg;
        public short wParamL;
        public short wParamH;
    }
    struct MouseInputData
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public uint mouseData;
        public MouseEventFlags dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }
    [Flags]
    enum MouseEventFlags : uint
    {
        MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001,
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004,
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
        MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080,
        MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100,
        MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800,
        MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,
        MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000
    }
    enum SendInputEventType : int
    {
        InputMouse,
        InputKeyboard,
        InputHardware
    }

    public static void ClickLeftMouseButton()
    {
        INPUT mouseDownInput = new INPUT();
        mouseDownInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dx = 1809;
        mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dy = 93;
        mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        INPUT mouseUpInput = new INPUT();
        mouseUpInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dx = 1809;
        mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dy = 93;
        mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
    }
    public static void ClickRightMouseButton()
    {
        INPUT mouseDownInput = new INPUT();
        mouseDownInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        INPUT mouseUpInput = new INPUT();
        mouseUpInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't work as you think it would - meaning, you can't have 2 cursors - where you have one moving freely and another one clicking where you please.

You can ofcourse send click event with a pos to a window, but not in desktop in general.

Comment: How can i send a click at a specific position or a button input to a program? Do you have a keyword which i can use for further research?

Comment: Yes, search for `C++ window send mouse event`
You can also just check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245607/windows-send-mouse-keyboard-event-to-background-window

Comment: Go to codeproject.com and search for global mouse keyboard library.